# Do not resort on changing cell data table sorter

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have implemented tablesorter. Problem is i have inlide editing applied to `<td>` and also i am handling checkboxes in `<td>`s. I have child rows mechanism also applied.

Problem is that when ever i change any `<td>` data before any of child rows it works fine. But if i edit any `tr > td` that comes after the `childrows tr`. I get `uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of 16` at this line

`c.cache[tbdy].normalized[row][c.columns].$row = $row; jquery.tablesorter.js:909`

I want to stop resorting on my cell changes. The only sorting should be done when and only when user clicks the headers.

Here is how i am configuring :

```
// Table sorter
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("#tablesorter").tablesorter({
        theme : 'default',
        headerTemplate : '{content}{icon}',
        widgets : [ "columns" ],
    });
});
```

Comment: What inline editing are you using? Have you tried the [editable widget](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-editable.html)? Have you tried setting the [`resort` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#resort) to `false`?

Comment: actually i already used that inline editing bootstrap plugin. After that i got requirement for tablesorter. Yes i tried resort false too. Actually the problem is something with child rows.